# How to access the parameter given by hx-include in django views

Tags: django, django-views, htmx

I am trying to access a parameter in a createview passed by the hx-include function, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere, and when I do, it doesn't work.

html:

```
<button
  id="deleteService"
  hx-post="{% url 'planner:create' %}"
  hx-include="[name='id']"
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-light btn-outline-black btn-sm"
  name="delete"
>Elimina</button>
```

and

```
<button
  hx-include="[name='{{ venue }}']"
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  Submit
</button>
```

I tried

```
self.request.POST['name']
self.request.POST['id']
self.request.POST.get['name']
self.request.POST.get('name')
```

The errors are:

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

and without .get:

django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object which is a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key. So you can use the `.get()` getter method on it. You need to provide the name of the included form input as the first parameter. In this case it's `id`:

```
self.request.POST.get('id')
```